# What are the supported cipher suites in sim800c?

Tags: ssl, at-command, sim800

I'm trying to communicate with a server that uses SSL/TLS but has some limited cipher suites.
How can I get a list of supported cipher suites in my sim800c to see if it can communicate with the server?

Comment: Do you have a test server that you can use to test your connection attempts? Better if it is an OpenSSL server.

Comment: unfortunately no.

Comment: B plan. Do you have administrator rights in a PC/Workstation with a public IP address?

Comment: no, but i can rent a cheap VPS for testing purposes.

Comment: The goal is connecting to your server with your modem with a sniffer such as Wireshark on server side. In fact the first handshake message, the *Hello message*, contains the list of supported cipher suites supported by it.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a ssl server. You can understan it also with a tcp listening socket. Even with another modem, if you are able to set it in listening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the test environment that [@roberto-caboni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11336762/roberto-caboni) suggested. I tested with both SIM800L and SIM800C. Cipher suites are the same.

The results are:

```
/* SIM800L firmware revision */
AT+CGMR

Revision:1418B05SIM800L24

OK

/* SIM800C firmware revision */
AT+CGMR

Revision:1418B08SIM800C24_BT

OK

/* I wiresharked a SLL connection to my server, the results:
Cipher Suites (9 suites)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x0004)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x0005)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0016)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0013)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x0009)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 (0x0003)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x0012)
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Revision: **1418B09SIM800C24_TLS**

```
Cipher Suites (10 suites)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003c)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
```